What is the injector pipeline stage in this RISC-V core?
The cores in the Efinix Sapphire SOC FPGA IP core have 6 pipeline stages (fetch, injector, decode, execute, memory and write back).
What is or might be the injector stage? I can't find it explained anywhere!
Source: https://www.efinixinc.com/support/ip/riscv-sapphire.php

Take a look at the VexRiscv page here: https://github.com/SpinalHDL/VexRiscv There is a IBusSimplePlugin adding this stage

@EugeneSh. That's one of my bookmarked pages -- particularly, in fact, because of the injector. I had liked the idea and wanted to come back someday to dig into it more deeply. Nice catch for the OP.

AtonDuke, I don't think you've really been putting in much effort. You need to up the ante a bit. I came across the page linked by @EugeneSh entirely on my own and I wasn't even looking for an injector. I bookmarked it because that idea caught my attention. The fact that you can say "I can't find it explained anywhere!" can only mean you haven't looked much or haven't been willing to read a little bit of code and some of nearby comments. I conclude you haven't really applied yourself to your own question. Put in some effort, teach us what you picked up, and then ask a more specific question.
